# How to query for the most popular job tags in Data Explorer

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-explorer, jobs

I'm just looking for a way to query the most popular tags in Stack Overflow Jobs, but I can't find anything related to it, I mean, a Jobs column or table or so. Is there a means to accomplish that task?

Comment: You could try parsing our [RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed).

Answer (score 3):

Job tags or any other data related to Stack Overflow Jobs are not in the [Data Explorer schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) nor in the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

You can't query for them that way, or any other way for that matter.